# DrupalGap - dynamically load html content

Tags: jquery, cordova, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm trying to use DrupalGap in my Cordova project, so I have a custom module and some pages assigned to menu items. And there is one page that has collapsible widget as content and I want to load some html content on expand event. Which is why I included additional loadMapsOnExpand.js file in settings.js:

```
Drupal.modules.custom['my_module'] = {
    includes: [{ name: 'loadMapsOnExpand' }]
};
```

But it does not work, on expand items have still no content. Html files for loading are fine because the same code works as expected without DrupalGap implementation. What am I doing wrong? 
Please help me to figure out, I searched internet but till now did not find the answer.
And many many thanks for your time!!!

loadMapsOnExpand.js contains the following code:

```
$('#klg_map').collapsible({
  expand: function(event, ui) {
     $('#klg_map_details').load("klagenfurtMapDetails.html",
       function(responseTxt,statusTxt,xhr){
         if(statusTxt=="error")
           alert("Error: "+xhr.status+": "+xhr.statusText);
       });
  }
});
```

my_module.js contains the following code:

```
function my_module_map_page() {
  try {
    var content = {};
    content['my_collapsibleset'] = {
      theme: 'collapsibleset',
      items: [
        { header: 'Klagenfurt', content: '<div id="klg_map_details"></div>',
            attributes: {
                'id': 'klg_map'
            }
        },
        { header: 'Wien', content: '<div id="wien_map_details"></div>',
            attributes: {
                'id': 'wien_map'
            } 
        }
      ]
    };
    return content;
  }
  catch (error) { console.log('my_module_map_page - ' + error); }
}
```

Comment: I usually do not have luck with adding jQuery event handlers like `$('#klg_map').collapsible(...);`, they always seem to get ignored. Instead I'll typically attach an attribute directly to the html element to handle the event I'm looking for, and then pass the event along to a function.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a quick response! Unfortunately, the attribute approach did not work for me. I tried many different ways of attaching that event through attribute, but no one worked:
attributes: {
                'id': 'klg_map',
                //, 
                //onexpand : 'alert("Hi!");' 
                //expand: 'alert("Hi!");' 
                //onclick: 'alert("Hi!");' 
                //click: 'alert("Hi!");'
                //'expand': 'alert("Hi!");' 
                //'onclick': 'alert("Hi!");' ....
            }

Comment: So, what I've done was attaching pageinit eventhandler http://www.drupalgap.org/node/154, loading in this handler my loadMapsOnExpand.js and editing path to the loaded files in the way 'app/modules/custom/my_module/includes/...':

Comment: `function my_module_map_page_pageinit(){
  try {
    drupalgap_add_js('app/modules/custom/my_module/includes/loadMapsOnExpand.js');
  }
  catch (error) { 
    console.log('my_module_install - ' + error); 
  }
}`